# Trying to run this generalised linear model to find the effect on mass of crickets by multiple random effects and I am getting this following error

Tags: r

I am trying to run a glm model to check the variation in the mass of cricket which could be affected by age(numeric), altitude(High or low), temperature(two different temperatures) and the incubators(4 different incubators) they are kept it.

I have tried the glm model which seems to be fine theoretically. The data on excel is all checked as well. I am assuming I have to convert some of the data into binary or some sorts.

```
glm(crick$Mass ~ crick$Altitude*crick$Age + crick$Altitude*crick$suare(Altitude) + 1/crick$Nymph.ID + 1/crick$Population + crick$Temperature*crick$Altitude + 1/crick$Incubator)
```

This is the code I am trying to run.

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : attempt to apply non-function this is the error message.

Comment: What do you expect when you run `crick$suare(Altitude)`?

Comment: I am sorry that was an error. glm(crick$Mass ~ crick$Altitude*crick$Weighing + crick$Altitude*crick$square(Altitude) + 1/crick$Nymph.ID + 1/crick$Population + crick$Temperature*crick$Altitude + 1/crick$Incubator)  That is the full code. I am trying to find out if there is any significant difference in the growth rate of the crickets because of keeping them in two different temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly specify the formula (e.g. see examples in `?glm`). Try

```
glm(Mass ~ Altitude*Age + 1/Nymph.ID + 1/Population + Temperature*Altitude + 1/Incubator, data = cricks)
```

Note that I excluded `Altitude*suare(Altitude)` which is invalid R syntax for formulas. You'll have to explain more what you're trying to go with here.

Comment: Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(y, mu) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(eta, offset) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(y, mu) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors This is the error I am getting after using the rectified code you provided me with.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example. I suspect your data is not in a proper format. @vinayakahegde

Comment: Hello, the formula did work. The data is in proper format. I do not know how to go further. I have 4 different glm now. 1) Glm to check the change in mass when the crickets were weighed on the day they were born. 2) Glm to check the change in mass when crickets were weighed the second time (13 days later, 26 and 39) (3) Is this the correct way to see if there is an effect on mass or do I do it all in just one glm?

Comment: @vinayakahegde that sounds like a question more appropriate for crossvalidated.com.